# Panniers and handlebar pack

Tags: panniers

I am planning to tour and would prefer highly visible panniers and handlebar packs.  Also waterproof.  Do racks come with panniers? Suggested brands please?

Comment: Welcome - please read the [tour] to learn how the site works.  Specifically, product recommendations are off topic because they're not long-term useful, and tend to be quite regionalised.

Answer (score 4):

Racks generally do not come paired with panniers, although there are some exceptions. Waterproof panniers are widely available. There are some high-vis panniers out there, and some that have reflective patches.

We generally avoid specific product recommendations here on bicycles.se, but Ortlieb is a standby pannier maker.

Comment: The main exception to the racks and panniers being sold separately is a few varieties where the interconnection system between them is custom.

Answer (score 1):

Racks and panniers are separate items. Buy the best waterproof panniers you can. A small pocket on the outside for tools, oil, a pump and a tube is always nice. If you are travelling you want fully waterproof. They will likely cost $200 each, give or take. Don't scrimp on this item.
Remember though, watch the sizing. They can get heavy when filled.Only you will know how much you can carry up the hills.

Answer (score 0):

Did a 500mile tour in college with panniers. I just shopped at the local outfitters store. It's not a specific product but the racks I used had Black- in the name. Honestly can't remember the full name. You want a solid rack fit so no wobblies, I appreciated the mount system to my fork/frame braze-ons. Don't skimp on rack quality, you want a light frame to mount, but a firm metal. Oh, n be friends with the local mechanic, you might need to swap out longer allen bolts for same braze-on hole fender/rack mounting. I'm not ashamed to have been bribed with pizza as a wrench turner ;D... The panniers I had hooked on the top and had an attached bungee looped system on bottom to attach, EZ off/on to pack into a tent n secure. My panniers were purple, but I put reflectors, red blinky lights and high viz reflective tape on them too. LOLz, I get your waterproof idea, we had rain in August at the end of summer on South Pacific coast, go figure. Weather similar to the Hawaiian Islands, blue skies, then mild rainfall and unprepared for it. Two words, plastic bags... Made ponchos n wrapped everything we didn't want wet. Don't forget fenders, actually liked this the best, no butt skid marks! Oh, n test run everything weighted with books n junk a bit, then look for hardware coming loose before the ride. Happy n safe trails to you!